# Trying to get back button on webKit

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Real newbie here,
Have added a webpage to my main controller which takes up full page,
but there is no back button
the webview just take over the whole screen
i would like to get a back button on it if possible
will add code below

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: Embed your `ViewController` into `UINavigationController`. Are you adding this `ViewController` programmatically or via `Storyboard`?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on where you want to `go back`:

- if you want to dismiss the current view controller, you can `push` the view controller with a navigation controller, you will get a `back` button for free.
- Or if you don't have a navigation controller, you can add a button in you view controller, for example drag a `UIButton` onto you view controller in the storyboard, and create an outlet var in your code:

```
@IBOutlet var backButton: UIButton!
```

And then adding a `goBack` function for the button:

```
@IBAction func goBack() {
    presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

- If by `going back`, you mean going back in the history of the web browsing, you can drag a `UIButton` onto you view controller in the storyboard, and create an outlet var in your code:

```
@IBOutlet var backButton: UIButton!
```

And then adding a `goBack` function for the button:

```
@IBAction func goBack() {
    webView.goBack()
}
```